Kaleido RuntimeError

I create a virtual environment using

python3 -m venv venv


Activate

source venv/bin/activate


Install Plotly package

pip install plotly


Try to run the following script dft.py

#!./venv/bin/python3
from math import pi

from plotly.graph_objects import Figure, Scatter
from plotly.io import full_figure_for_development as ffdf

dr: int = 1000
dv: list[float] = [2.0*pi*i/dr for i in range(dr + 1)]


# plot the result
fig = Figure()
fig.add_trace(Scatter(x=dv, y=dv))

# save the figure
ffdf(fig, warn=False)
fig.write_image('a.pdf', engine="kaleido")



An error appears

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/r/ma/fa/./dft.py", line 20, in <module>
    ffdf(fig, warn=False)
  File "/home/r/ma/fa/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/plotly/io/_kaleido.py", line 327, in full_figure_for_development
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: 
Full figure generation requires the kaleido package,
which can be installed using pip:
    $ pip install -U kaleido


Install kaleido

pip install -U kaleido


When I am trying to execute the script I get the following error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/r/ma/fa/./dft.py", line 6, in <module>
    from plotly.io import full_figure_for_development as ffdf
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1412, in _handle_fromlist
  File "/home/r/ma/fa/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/_plotly_utils/importers.py", line 36, in __getattr__
    class_module = importlib.import_module(rel_module, parent_name)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/r/ma/fa/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/plotly/io/_kaleido.py", line 10, in <module>
    scope = PlotlyScope()
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/r/ma/fa/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/kaleido/scopes/plotly.py", line 63, in __init__
    raise RuntimeError("Kaleido now requires that chrome/chromium is installed separately. Kaleido will try to detect it automatically, but the environmental error \"BROWSER_PATH\" can also be set")
RuntimeError: Kaleido now requires that chrome/chromium is installed separately. Kaleido will try to detect it automatically, but the environmental error "BROWSER_PATH" can also be set


I was using this scheme to draw charts many times in last years, everything was fine. According to the release history of the Kaleido package pypi.org, Kaleido has been upgraded yesterday to version 0.4.2.
What is chrome/chromium? There is no such package on PyPi. Do anyone has an idea how to fix the error?

Which web browser do you have installed? You can't find Chrome/chromium on pypi because they're web browsers, not python packages. Chrome is referring to the specific Google Chrome browser. As for chromium, I'm not sure if they specifically want the Chromium Browser or one of the many that are based on it.

@kevin41 Yandex. I was using this browser before the error occured, never have Chrome installed.

@kevin41 btw I installed an older version of kaleido pip install 'kaleido==0.2.1' --force-reinstall and everything works fine, however the problem remains open

The latest version of Kaleido requires the chrome browser to be installed. See this [article}(https://plotly.com/blog/kaleido-the-next-generation/) for more information.

I had the same error as you suggested, I forced the previous version.
In the Release history [https://pypi.org/project/kaleido/#history][1]
you can see the they YANKED the release for too many breaking changes.

There is also another way, according to docs, it is possible to use the Orca engine instead of Kaleido, but I have not tried this approach yet.
